# How can I make a discord bot that will message user a specific code when he runs a command? Kind of like an account generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically I'm trying to make a code for my discord.js bot that will message users with a steam key when they run a specific command. I came up with the idea when I thought of giving VIP members a special feature where they can get a steam key every day by just using a simple command so that my private messages don't get spammed. I will be providing the steam keys. The feature should message a unique steam key to each user who uses a command, and should not message the same key to different users. I've coded so many other commands but this one is really troubling me, I'm not able to figure out how I can create such a feature. Please help.

So this is basically for my discord server and should be coded in discord.js. I can create a code but the thing that troubles me is that I cannot stop the repetition of the keys...

Comment: What have you tried so far? are you getting any error or some approach which is not working as per your expectations?

Comment: Maintain a pool of unsent keys and a table of users with the keys they got in a database.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

As [Ricky Mo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10317684/ricky-mo) commented,

> Maintain a pool of unsent keys and a table of users with the keys they got in a database.

This works because a user can receive a key from the unused stash, and once it's removed, it can't be given out again. If you want to allow only one key per user (or implement a cooldown) you can store users and their key.

A real database is a much better option than a JSON file, but your possible choices are too much to cover in one simple example.

---

**Example Setup**

`keys.json`:

```
{
  "__UNUSED": [
    "ABCD",
    "1234",
    "0000"
  ],

  "userIDHere": "keyHere"
}
```

Inside command:

```js
/* Async context needed for 'await' (meaning within an async function). */

const fs = require('fs');
const keys = require('./keys.json');

try {
  // Ensure the user hasn't claimed a key already.
  if (keys[message.author.id]) return await message.author.send(':x: You already claimed a key.');

  // Ensure there's keys remaining.
  if (keys.__UNUSED.length === 0) {
    console.error('Out of keys.');
    return await message.author.send(':x: Sorry, no keys are available to claim right now.');
  }

  // Grab the first key (no need to randomize).
  const key = keys.__UNUSED[0];

  // Send the user the key, then remove it from the pool, catch any errors.
  await message.author.send(`Here's your key: ||${key}||`);

  keys.__UNUSED.splice(1);
  keys[message.author.id] = key;

  fs.writeFileSync('./keys.json', JSON.stringify(keys));
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

> ...I thought of giving VIP members a special feature where they can get a [S]team key every day...

If you want to incorporate this, you could set an interval or create a [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) job to remove the user from the JSON/database every 24 hours.